# texture address mode artifact on environment cube map in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

I am having some problems getting rid of an artifact in my WP7 XNA application. After figuring out how to create and load a TextureCube and render objects using the EnvironmentMapEffect, I noticed an artifact in the reflection rendered on the object. It looks like the cube texture I'm employing is using a wrap texture address mode instead of clamp texture address mode.

The weird thing is that the problem only appears on the device (LG Optimus 7), the emulator doesn't have this issue.

Does anyone know if this is a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

I am attaching a 'camera-shot' of the issue on my device.
<< [reflection artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/502MU.jpg) >>

Comment: Are you setting the SamplerState? graphics.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;

Comment: Yes, even after setting the sampler state, the result is the same. A texture needs to be set anyway on the EnvironmentMapEffect, otherwise the object appears black. I've created a 1x1 white texture for it to appear like you see in the screenshot. I'm afraid that setting that SamplerState only affects this texture, and not the environment cube map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the environment cube map employed the second SamplerState in the collection. Now it works on the device too, using what Scott suggested, but on the second index:

```
// clamp texture addressing for environment map
_effect.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[1] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest some documentation regarding environment cube maps on WP7? I found very little info on this, most of it relates to building the cube texture (which isn't that easy and I found it useful as well). For example, another problem I have is that rotating a sphere rendered using an environment cube map renders a wobbly image, which I don't remember happening in OpenGL.